# Eclipse_Pleiades版_アクティブなビュー内のテキストが読めないので前景色の設定を教えてください

Tags: java, eclipse

こんにちは。

Eclipse_PleiadesAllinOne版をインストールしたのですが、アクティブなビュー内の選択されたテキストの前景色（黒）が背景色（濃紺）につぶれてしまって見えません。設定 > 色とフォント あたりなのかなあと思うのですがどこで設定したらよいのでしょうか。

Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
pleiades-4.6.3-java-win-64bit-jre_20170422.zipを使用しました。

下図ではパッケージ・エクスプローラの中で選択されたテキストが潰れてしまっています。
別のビューをアクティブにすると背景色がグレーになって読めるようになります。
（下図ではアウトラインのように読めるようになる）

[image: 潰れて見えない]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決しました。windowsのパフォーマンスオプション > ウィンドウとボタンに視覚スタイルを使用する にチェックを入れるとテキストが潰れずに視認できるようになりました。 画像のようなクラシックスタイルにPleiadesが対応していないかも？